# Intellij IdeaVIM visual selection wonky?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

Given :

```
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("SOME PAGE"));
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("2911030417"));
```

When you select `selenium.isTextPresent` in order to execute a macro on all occurrences the plugin is non-compliant. Is there some explanation for why the visual selection behaves so strangely?

Expected to 'v3w' to make the selection then '*' to throw it into a register; then ex-command :/qq50@aq to replace next 50 matches.

I'm refactoring a rather large test code with upgraded dependencies.

`v3w` to visual select the 3 words

`*`   to dump it into register

`:<CR>/` to recall it in ex command mode

`:qqn50@anq` to record a new macro which replays my original macro say 50X

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bug. I have created a bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-3238/

Comment: Thanks for confirming, glad it was reproducible by somebody else.